# Limit of $\log (\log( ... \log((n)^ {(n-1)^ {....}})))$

Tags: limits

This is a spinoff of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13274/193)

Defining

$$f_0(x) = x$$
$$f_n(x) = \log(f_{(n-1)} (x)) \space (\forall n>0)$$

and

$$a_0 = 1$$
$$a_{n+1} = (n+1)^{a_n} \space (\forall n>0)$$

How to calculate

$$\lim_{n \to \infty } f_n(a_n) $$

(an "experiment" [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Log%5BLog%5BLog%5BLog%5BLog%5BLog%5BLog%5BLog%5BLog%5BLog%5BLog%5B11%5E10%5E9%5E8%5E7%5E6%5E5%5E4%5E3%5E2%5E1%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D), but (beware) I think WolframAlpha is using an approximate representation in powers of 10)

**Edit**

A table with the first few values (made with aid of [hypercalc](http://mrob.com/pub/comp/hypercalc/hypercalc-javascript.html), as per Gottfried's suggestion in comments)

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 n & f_n(a_n) \\
 0 & 1. \\
 1 & 0. \\
 2 & -0.366513 \\
 3 & -0.239279 \\
 4 & -0.0771089 \\
 5 & -0.06133128660211943 \\
 6 & -0.06133124230008346 \\
 7 & -0.06133124230008346 \\
 8 & -0.06133124230008346
\end{array}$$

Comment: (prev. comment removed) It does look like it converges! $f_5$,$f_6$, and $f_7$ all are approximately -.0613312.

Comment: Haven't been able to prove it yet. It's definitely monotonically increasing: For all $n>2$ we have $n>e$, so that $n^{a_{n-1}}=a_n>e^{a_{n-1}}$. Then $f_n(a_n)>f_n(e^{a_{n-1}})=f_{n-1}(a_{n-1})$. I'm stuck on proving that it's bounded. You can see that sums of the form $e-2\log(3)$, $e^e-3^2\log(4)$, $e^{e^e}-4^{3^2}\log(5)$, etc. would all have to be greater than zero for boundedness, but I'm having trouble proving it. Clearly the condition depends strongly on the magnitude of $e$ though.

Comment: by "having trouble proving it" I meant "Having trouble proving that all those terms are greater than zero"

Comment: @belisarius: I'm not sure about your numerical values.  I get the following 1, 0, -0.3665129206, -0.2392792745, 0.04639873165, 0.2116219343, 0.2785508275, 0.3021805399, 0.3099107249, 0.3123003883, etc.

Comment: @SidiousLord Yep. I got some index displacement in my table. Corrected, thanks

Comment: Have you tried the "hypercalc" at Robert Manufo's site? Possibly one can get more terms of your sequence with that...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Nice suggestion. Done! Seems it converges fast!

Comment: An interesting variant seems to be the sequence $\log(2) $ , $\log(\log(2^3)) $ , $ \log(\log(\log(2^{3^4}))) $ , ... ($\log $ means here the *ln* ). Does it also converge? I went up to top exponent 16 on the hypercalc-site, but didn't arrive at a conclusion....

Comment: I went upt to top exponent $(2^7) $ on the hypercalc site stepping to $2^k$ as the top-exponents. With the function $g(x) =  a= 2\^3\^4\^...\^(2^x);  b=\ln°^{2^x-1}(a) ; return(b) $ (where the superscript at the ln indicates iterations) I get the following table: $\begin{array} {}
g(1) = 0.6931471805599453 \\
g(2) = 1.393254144068342  \\ 
g(3) = 2.781949728441699 \\
g(4) = 3.7909671825168587 \\ 
g(5) = 4.710536164389033 \\
g(6) = 5.58566765572222 \\
g(7) = 6.432348427854444 \\
 \end{array} \\ $

Comment: ... and two more : $\begin{array} {}
g(8) = 7.258605780274824 \\
g(9) = 8.069295828717253 \\
 \end{array} \\ $ . Hmmm...

Answer (score 4):

*This is not an answer as one would like to write one; but there is still only one other answer around so far - thus a second attempt might be helpful anyway even if not yet complete.*

I've come across a [claim](http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=168&pid=2162#pid2162), that Ramanujan has proved, that the function
$$ f(x) = 1 + {e^x \over 2^3} + {e^{e^x} \over 2^{3^4}}  + {e^{e^{e^x}} \over 2^{3^{4^5}}}  +  ...   $$ 
is entire. This implies, that the sequence of terms approach zero ***for each*** *x*, and thus that the denominators outgrow the numerators. By this we see, that the iterated logarithms applied to the numerators, when iterated *h* times until they arrive at x, and then applied with the same number of iterations to the denominators must arrive at some value arbitrarily greater than *x* for each *k*'th term after $ k \gt K$ for some fixed $K $.

Thus we have the first information, that $$ \ln^{[h]} \left(2^{3^{4^{\ldots ^h}}} \right)$$ where $ \ln^{[h]} $ means the h'fold iteration of the $\ln $ , diverges with increasing *h* .

The second information is the trivial one, that if the entries in the iterated exponential are all equal, and specifically equal the base of natural logarithms $e$ , 
$$ \ln^{[h]} \left(e^{e^{e^{\ldots ^e}}} \right)$$
then the iterated logarithm of the iterated exponential always arrives at the same constant value for increasing *h*.

The third information is then, that the iterated exponential in the initial question has *decreasing* terms, 
$$ \ln^{[h]} \left(h^{\ldots ^{4^{3^2}}} \right)$$
so possibly using the argumentation of Ramanujan one can also prove, that the expression asked for, actually converges to a fixed value. Unfortunately I don't have access to that argumentation of Ramanujan, but here is a [link in the tetration-forum](http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=168&pid=2162#pid2162) to (possibly) more helpful information how to retrieve that source.

Answer (score 3):

Your sequence is convergent :

Fist, it is well-defined, because it is defined for $n=2$, and for $n\ge2$,
$\log^{n+1}(a_{n+1}) = \log^n(a_n \log(n+1)) = \log^{n-1}(\log a_n + \log^2(n+1))$ and $\log^2(n+1) > 0$, which also shows that the sequence is increasing from that point.

Let $x_n = \log^n(a_n)$. By using that for all $x,y > 0, \log(x+y) \le \log x + y/x$ and that $\log$ is increasing, we get :

$x_{n+1} = \log^{n-1}(\log a_n + \log^2(n+1)) 
\le \log^{n-2}(\log^2 a_n + \log^2(n+1)/ \log a_n) \\
\le \ldots \le \log^n(a_n) + \log^2(n+1)/ (\log a_n \log^2 a_n \ldots \log^{n-1} a_n) \\
= x_n + \log^2(n+1)/(\exp(x_n) \ldots \exp^{n-1}(x_n))$

And since we know $x_n$ is increasing, it is easy to show that $x_{n+1} - x_n$ is summable, and that it converges extremely fast (the number of correct digits grows tetrationnally). There should not be enough room in the observable universe to write all the correct digits of $x_7$

Answer (score 1):

You indeed have
x_n = log^(n) ( n^...^1 )

= log^(n-2) ( (n-2)^...^1 * log(n-1) + log( log( n )))

which does not simplify further, but allows asymptotical expansion, via

log( A+B ) = log( A ) + log(1 + B/A) = log(A) - sum((-B/A)^k, k=1..oo).

Unfortunatley, this is inside the "innermost" of the n-2 exterior logs.
However, the log(log n) term is quickly negligable w.r.t. the (n-2)^...^1 log(n-1).
Therefore, log^(n-2) ( (n-2)^...^1 * log(n-1)) is a very good approximation to x_n, for large n. 
For the same reason, neglecting the log(n-1) yields still a very good approximation to x_n, for large n. 
But this means we end up with x_(n-2) as very good approximation to x_n.
This can be seen as "heuristic" (well, maybe just a little better than "hand waving") justification of the convergence.

OTOH, quantification of the "very good" is possible, and yields a proof. (Probably the same as above.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this sequence converges. First note that $f_n(a_n)=f_{n-1}(a_{n-1})+log(...(log(n))...)$ where log is composed n-times. Then note that

$\lim_{n\to\infty}log(...(log(n))...)=0$ where log is composed n-times. Then if $f_n(a_n)$ converges then $-f_n(a_n)$ converges as well. With that notice

$\lim_{n\to\infty}-f_n(a_n)=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}(f_{k+1}(a_{k+1})-f_k(a_k))=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\int_{1}^{log(...(log(k))...))}\frac{1}{x}dx
=\lim_{n\to\infty}-\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\int_{log(...(log(k))...))}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x}$

where log is composed k-times in the integral.

Comment: Log[Log[Log[3^2]]] evaluates to -0.239279..., Log[Log[2]] + Log[Log[Log[3]]] evaluates to -2.73046 (same if you just add Log[Log[3]], composing n-1 times). We have $\log(\log(\log(3^2)))=\log(\log(2\log(3)))=\log(\log(2)+\log(\log(3)))$, yes, but you can't move that addition outside that last logarithm.